# Sentry: Body and headers parameters don't show in exceptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, sentry, issue-tracking

I'm using sentry to trace the code and have a list of error of my application. This application has a backend and two different iterators.

The configuration of all of them are equals except the value of DSN.

However, the exceptions in the backend show body and headers parameters but the iterators don't show the body and headers parameters in the exception.

The backend is who make calls to these iterators.

How is that possible? What am I doing wrong?

**Edit I:**

The code added in my index.js is:

```
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/node";
import * as Tracing from "@sentry/tracing";

Sentry.init({
    dsn: config.sentry_dsn,
    integrations: [
        // enable HTTP calls tracing
        new Sentry.Integrations.Http({ tracing: true }),
        // enable Express.js middleware tracing
        new Tracing.Integrations.Express({
        // to trace all requests to the default router
        app,
        // alternatively, you can specify the routes you want to trace:
        // router: someRouter,
        }),
    ],
    environment: config.node_env,
    // We recommend adjusting this value in production, or using tracesSampler
    // for finer control
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
});

// RequestHandler creates a separate execution context using domains, so that every
// transaction/span/breadcrumb is attached to its own Hub instance
app.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler());
// TracingHandler creates a trace for every incoming request
app.use(Sentry.Handlers.tracingHandler());

app.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());
```

Comment: what is an iterator in this context?

Comment: @burnettk Hi!!! I have updated the information in the original post. Thanks for your appreciated help!!!